# UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend equivalent on Android?

Tags: android

Is there any code that allows the same function in Android that UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend does in iOS ? I have an app that I need to completely suspend on exit and not allow to run in the background. I know i will be told its not necessary or dangerous but for the purposes of the app I need to have this function available if possible.

Comment: So you want to overcome the multitask feature of the system so that your app does not "run" in the background? If you give no task to do in the background, nothing will happen you know. Tell us more about your needs and why.

Comment: It's an app for an outside sales force who arent the most tech savvy and having it run in background would impose amongst other things security issues and also its sup up to release cache on exit (which is needed as well)

Comment: How would it be a security issue?

Comment: With regards to releasing cache, please implement `onTrimMemory()` and/or `onLowMemory()` and release your caches then. Any "security issues" most likely can be handled better in other ways, but only if you can explain which particular issues concern you.

Comment: basically security issue is a phone getting stolen and being able to access specific areas that would be available due to cache, and i understand the on trim and onLowMemory i just want total cache release on closing everysingle time regardless of memory.